# What alloy am I making (Al-Bi)

Tags: metallurgy, alloys

I have been melting aluminum in a DIY furnace for a few months in order to make lost wax casts. I was thinking that since bismuth has a much lower melting point than aluminum, that I could add a small amount of bismuth to lower the melting point (9 parts Al, 1 part Bi). Qualitatively this seems to be working. But I am confused.

Looking up a [phase diagram for Al-Bi](https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11669-014-0300-3/MediaObjects/11669_2014_300_Fig1_HTML.gif), I find:

[image: phase diagram for Al-Bi]

Which if I understand it correctly seems to mean that the melting point actually went up. Am I reading it correctly? If both metals separately have a lower melting point than the alloy at that ratio (and I am not reaching the new melting point), then what am I making?

Besides lowering the melting point, my hope was also to lower the viscosity so that the mix fills in my mold better. Will adding bismuth help accomplish this goal? Should I be adding tin instead? Is there a tin-bis-al ratio that would yield minimum viscosity at temperatures below 1500 °F (ideally mostly made out of Al)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making anything ,usable. Bi does not raise the melt point until over 3.4 % Bi, that is lost in this diagram. If your aim is to make aluminum castings , look in a book and do it the way the rest of the world does, add Si. At about 12% Si the melting point is down to about 998 F, about as low as you will get . And,suprise, this is a common composition for aluminum alloy castings.

Comment: The melting point of silicon is 2500 F. But if I add silicon powder to the molten aluminum at 1200F, will it alloy? or will the silicon stay solid?

Comment: Also does it have to be pure silicon, or will SiO2 work too?

Comment: The ASM reference lists pure silicon or aluminum / silicon mater alloy to add Si, which sounds typical. Apparently sand ( Si O 2) won't work. The 12 Si alloy is A 132, also a 9 Si alloy D132. Also if melting temperature is your only criteria; 10 Mg melts at about 860 F. Also Zn alloys . As I suggested ,get a book.

Comment: are there any books you recommend? I assume there aren't any books titled "diy metallurgy for backyard enthusiasts". I doubt my forge can get past 1500F consistently.

Comment: American Society for Metals has many publications , there should be something to help.  But I doubt anything for the "backyard".

Comment: it looks like asm handbook 15 : casting hes useful advice for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Combining metals does not result in uniform melting points according to the melting points of the components.  A classic example is tin & lead, the melting point of which varies according to the ratios, but I believe is always less than either of the component metals.

I supposed we'd need a chemist to explain why this is, but I submit that you should just not expect that melting points should be so straightforward.

Comment: so if I add molten aluminum at 660 C to molten bismuth at 660 C, would it instantly solidify when mixing? or would it stay melted but separated?

Comment: @IvanViti I don't know what it would do, that's the point.